# Parent and child pom with maven shade plugin

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml, maven-shade-plugin

I have a parent maven project with its pom and two child projects with their pom having a packaging in jar mode. These two child pom have a class of launch.
The problem is that each time I create a new child project, I need a new pom with a jar packaging.
The research goal is to create a parent pom in jar packaging mode that removes the MyChildLauncherCLass declaration and standardize the version of each child pom.

child 1 pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>myChildGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>myChildartifactId</artifactId>
        <version>myChildVersion</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>myChildArtifactId</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>../../webapp/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>../../webapp/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>MyChildLauncherCLass</Main-Class>
                                        <Child1Version>${project.version}</Child1Version>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

parent pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>myParentgroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>myParentArtifactId1</artifactId>
        <version>myParentVersion</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>myParentArtifactId2</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

    <dependencies>
        ... dependencies...
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                  <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                      <manifestEntries>
                        <Child1Version>${project.version}</Child1Version> <!-- How to do this generic for any child pom ???? -->
                      </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                  </transformers>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
        
</project>
```

How could I do it on my parent pom above

Comment: I'd try using [`<pluginManagement>`](https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/maven/content/pom.html#Plugin_Management) in your parent POM.

Comment: Remove `<sourceDirectory>../../webapp/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>` because you are doing something wrong... please make a full working example on GitHub or alike...

Comment: hi @GeroldBroser in my package parent i have   <artifactId>atori-batch</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>${project.artifactId}</name>. I want to change packaging pom to jar packaging and add shade plugin with <manifestEntries> tag to have a specific version for each child

Comment: hi @khmarbaise in my package parent i have   <artifactId>atori-batch</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>${project.artifactId}</name>. I want to change packaging pom to jar packaging and add shade plugin with <manifestEntries> tag to have a specific version for each child

Comment: Make a separate child only with the configuration for maven-shade-plugin add the needed childs as dependencies. You can not change the parent packaging from `pom` to `jar` because that will not work for a multi module build...

Comment: @khmarbaise There's no `<modules>` in the question's POM. Apparently there's just a parent ← child relationship,not an aggregator → modules relationship.

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise , how can i make separate child with configuration of maven-shade-plugin and add child as dependency. Can you give me an example.  I change packaging from pom to jar and i delete multi module for children

Answer (score 0):

Project structure:

```
+- parent
   + pom.xml ... <packaging>pom, <module>child1/<module>child1/<module>childN
   |
   +- child1
   |  +- pom.xml ... <parent>parent
   |  +- ... src/main, src/test, etc.
   |
   +- child2
   |  +- pom.xml ... <parent>parent
   |  +- ... src/main, src/test, etc. 
   |
   +- childN
      +- pom.xml ... <parent>parent
      +- ... src/main, src/test, etc.
```

#### Parent POM

```xml
    ...
    <build>
      <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>...</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                  <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                      <manifestEntries>
                        <ChildVersion>${project.version}</childVersion>
                      </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                      <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                    </transformer>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                      <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                    </transformer>
                  </transformers>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    ...
```

#### Child POMs

```xml
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                      <manifestEntries>
                        <Main-Class>Child[N]LauncherCLass</Main-Class>
                      </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
```